# HashMap (Get value which is from selected ID)

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have one problem which uses HashMap.

In hashmap I store array list with userData.
So for example I store data like: `userId, Username, Name, Surname`. And now I want to create when I enter in textbox userID, I will get Username as result, but if userID is not in Hashmap, I want to return nothing...

All I need is how to get right data for user if entered ID matches value in array then I will get Username as result.

Comment: don't provide examples with text. few lines of code can translate to a thousand words.

Answer (score 2):

I guess one of the good solution can be :-

**Create a User class** (if you already don't have one)

```
public class User {
  private String userId;
  private String username;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  ...
  ...
  //their getter and setters
  //create a good toString() method, it will be helpful

  }
```

And then create a HashMap of type

```
  Map<String,User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then whenever user enters the userID, go and call get() method of `userMap`. It should give you corresponding User object, null otherwise.

If it gives you null, print a default message like, `No user found!!` and if user object is returned, you definitely call `user.toString()` and return it.

Comment: Yes, that's okay, But how to print only Username, not all user data?

Comment: That's even easier, print `user.getUsername()` instead of user.toString()